# Freelancer TNG 2.7.6 Mod help?

Tags: mods, freelancer

I'm trying to find the Ancient's base in The Next Generation mod, but I can't seem to locate a jumpgate to the Void system from the Omicron Theta system.

I know this is a bit of a longshot that someone's played this decade-old game, and on top of that has this mod for it. I'm really going crazy trying to figure it out though!

Thanks in advance xx

Comment: I think you'll find that, unless I miss my guess, there are a TON of people on here who've played Freelancer.  Maybe not the mod, though :)

Comment: Aye, I have lots of fond memories playing freelancer.  Its a shame getting it to work on Win7 is such a big hassle.

Answer (score 4):

You can access that system from Magellan.  The gate is south of the Freeport in that system.

Answer (score 1):

in Omicron Theta go toward the northwest corner and you will find it.